# How to display sum result of column in last row

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

I need to print sum of last column as a total_sum under the last row. I have used connection string to get datas from sql server. How i will add row to print that result.

I used `DataGridView.Rows.Add()` but it is not adding row under that

```
private void Result_Click(object sender, EventArgs e
{
SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(conString);
con1.Open();
string q1 = "select * from Customer_Transaction where Cust_No ='C0001'";
string q2 = "select sum(Bill_Amount) as Total from   Customer_Transaction where Cust_No ='C0001'";
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q1, con1);
  SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(q2, con1);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

//ResultDataGrid.Rows.Add("TOTALS", q2);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
SqlDataAdapter ta = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
da.Fill(dataTable_customer_transaction_result);
ta.Fill(dataTable_customer_transaction_result);
ResultDataGrid.DataSource = dataTable_customer_transaction_result;
con1.Close();
da.Dispose();
ta.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Where is it adding the row instead? Use `ResultDataGrid.Rows.Add()` and then fill the cells with the values: `ResultDataGrid.Rows[ResultDataGrid.Rows.Count-1].Cells[0].Value = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();`

Comment: I'd suggest using `using` rather than `Dispose`.

Answer (score 1):

The only I see work around is get customer data in the dataTable_customer_transaction_result and then sum them. Here is sample code:

```
  SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(conString);
        con1.Open();
        string q1 = "select * from Customer_Transaction where Cust_No ='C0001'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q1, con1);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); ;

        //ResultDataGrid.Rows.Add("TOTALS", q2);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dataTable_customer_transaction_result);

        var totalSum = 0.0M;

        foreach (var row in dataTable_customer_transaction_result.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            totalSum += Convert.ToDecimal(row["Bill_Amount"]);
        }
```

You can use DataGridView to this on Databind event.

Another way is using RowDataBound event of the gridview. Please go through this article https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/77a82c/add-row-total-in-gridview-footer-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: here its showing error foreach (var row in dataTable_customer_transaction_result.Tables[0].Rows)  what i type instead Of "Tables"